# How to extract specific column keys and values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, extract

I currently have a dictionary containing a key, and around 30 columns of values in string and int format.

e.g.:

```
Message: '0409-01:51:02.577'
Arguments: (['29', '30', '37', '5463', '84338', 'ABCD', 'x-abc1', 'xxx', '1A234BCD5EFG67890H1234IJ', 'ABCDEF', '02DA', '123456789', '1234567890', '1234567890', '1A234BCD5', '911', '1A234BCD5EF', '0', '12', '7', '1', '_', 'XY', 'ABC', '1A234BCDEF', 'ABCDEF', '1A234BCD', '1A234BCD', '1A234BCDDFW', 'L', '1'],)
```

I'm trying to extract `` `k`, `v[5]`, `v[12]`, `v[28]`, `v[25]`, `v[22`], `v[23]`, `v[9]` `` in that order into a new dict or list.

I've tried varying between list and dict, I tried one line vs many.  I unfortunately can't change the incoming dict as I'm pulling data from four different sources to build this out.

```py
abcdef = ('ABC', 'DEF')

incoming_files = {0409-01:51:02.577:['29', '30', '37', '5463', '84338', 'ABCD', 'x-abc1', 'xxx', '1A234BCD5EFG67890H1234IJ', 'ABCDEF', '02DA', '123456789', '1234567890', '1234567890', '1A234BCD5', '911', '1A234BCD5EF', '0', '12', '7', '1', '_', 'XY', 'ABC', '1A234BCDEF', 'ABCDEF', '1A234BCD', '1A234BCD', '1A234BCDDFW', 'L', '1']}

tc_wfiles = {}
    for k, v in incoming_files.items():
        if any(c in v for c in abcdef):
            try:
                self.tc_wfiles[k] = incoming_files[k]
                self.tc_wfiles[k].append(incoming_files[k][5])
                self.tc_wfiles[k].append(incoming_files[k][12])
                self.tc_wfiles[k].append(incoming_files[k][28])
                self.tc_wfiles[k].append(incoming_files[k][25])
                self.tc_wfiles[k].append(incoming_files[k][22])
                self.tc_wfiles[k].append(incoming_files[k][23])
                self.tc_wfiles[k].append(incoming_files[k][9])
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

What should be happening is the key and those values are placed in a new dict or list.  What I'm getting however is the whole line in the key field and then the value items.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is my first time asking a question here, I hope my edit fits with what you're requesting and I'm sorry if it doesn't.  Still sort of new at this.

Comment: Sorry, but no it doesn't. `incoming_files` looks like it's a dictionary, but the variable isn't defined. Same for `abcdef` and `self.tc_wfiles`. In addition, that `logging.debug()` call probably has nothing whatsoever to do with the issue. Please put in only enough code that other folks can run and use to reproduce the problem and possibly tell you how to fix it (but no more).

Comment: Duly noted, I apologize for my missteps.

Comment: Jesse: Well, since that's _almost_ executable, I'll retract my close-vote—although it would also be helpful to know what the desired/expect output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question because you haven't indicated what the correct results should be...but if nothing else, perhaps this will provide you with some insights.

```
abcdef = ('ABC', 'DEF')
incoming_files = {'0409-01:51:02.577': ['29', '30', '37', '5463', '84338',
                                        'ABCD', 'x-abc1', 'xxx',
                                        '1A234BCD5EFG67890H1234IJ', 'ABCDEF',
                                        '02DA', '123456789', '1234567890',
                                        '1234567890', '1A234BCD5', '911',
                                        '1A234BCD5EF', '0', '12', '7', '1', '_',
                                        'XY', 'ABC', '1A234BCDEF', 'ABCDEF',
                                        '1A234BCD', '1A234BCD', '1A234BCDDFW',
                                        'L', '1']}

tc_wfiles = {}
for k, v in incoming_files.items():
    if any(c in v for c in abcdef):
        try:
            tc_wfiles[k] = [k]
            tc_wfiles[k].append(v[5])
            tc_wfiles[k].append(v[12])
            tc_wfiles[k].append(v[28])
            tc_wfiles[k].append(v[25])
            tc_wfiles[k].append(v[22])
            tc_wfiles[k].append(v[23])
            tc_wfiles[k].append(v[9])
        except IndexError as exc:
            print('exception:', exc)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(tc_wfiles)
```

Output:

```
{'0409-01:51:02.577': ['0409-01:51:02.577',
                       'ABCD',
                       '1234567890',
                       '1A234BCDDFW',
                       'ABCDEF',
                       'XY',
                       'ABC',
                       'ABCDEF']}
```